# ASP.NET HTTP handlers and global variables

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I have created HTTP handlers.

How do I create global variables for these handlers like I can with ASP.net web pages in  global.asax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the variables to the Application instance:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["MyGlobalVariable"] = myValue;
```

Or, if the variable only need to live for the life of an individual request, use the Context object's Items collection:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["MyGlobalVariable"] = myValue;
```

Again, that will live for only the life of a single request.

Answer (score 3):

If your handler is specified as reusable you can also use static class members.

Comment: thanks, this is a good alternative solution that I will investigate

Comment: Just because you say the handler is reusable doesn't mean that ALL calls to the handler will use the same instance, right? It just means an instance *can* be reused.